# Spring boot is unable to pick log4j2 dependency

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback, log4j2, slf4j

Unable to find similar issue so raising this. Sorry if it is repeated.

Trying to use log4j2 in a spring boot (version 1.5.9) application-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But somehow spring boot still looking for logback dependency (excluded logback dependency everywhere in mvn dependency tree)-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/classic/turbo/TurboFilter
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem.get(LoggingSystem.java:169)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem.get(LoggingSystem.java:160)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationStartingEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:229)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:209)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.starting(EventPublishingRunListener.java:69)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.starting(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:292)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134)
    at Test.main(Test.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ch.qos.logback.classic.turbo.TurboFilter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 17 more
```

Comment: do you have a log4j2 config file, springboot need it to detect log4j

Comment: Yes, log4j2.xml file is in classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Log4j2 configuration file is missing. Add the configuration file in your resources and that may solve the issue.

Comment: log4j2.xml is available in classpath.

Comment: Looks like Spring Boot automatically configures LogBack. So, if you have Spring boot starter dependency exclude starter-logging there as well.